# How to put 'null' into column using HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

How to build valid HQL string, which is equivalent to

UPDATE table SET field = null WHERE ....

Comment: may be a silly question, but, does this sql update work from some sql console? i.e. do you have maybe a constraint NOT NULL over the column 'field'?

Comment: The sql is ok - it works from console fine !

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean bulk HQL update? Try this

```
UPDATE myEntity e SET e.myProperty = null WHERE ...
```

You can also use a parameterized version of the above

```
UPDATE myEntity e SET e.myProperty = :param WHERE ...
```

In your code:

```
int updatedEntities = session.createQuery(updateQueryHQL)
  .setString( "param", myValue ) // or .setString( "param", null )
  .executeUpdate();
```

See [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct) for details.

If you're not doing bulk updates, you should just set your property to NULL and persist the entity normally.

Comment: Thanks, but ... both versions throw HibernateException !!! 

setString( "param", myValue )
executeUpdate();

works only when myValue is not null !!!

Comment: What kind of HibernateException (what does the error say)? Does your table allow NULLs in that column? Is that property actually a String or is it of some other type?

Comment: 1. The table column allow NULLs
2. The property is actually String (this same problem with column of type 'Date')
2. Hibernate Exception error unfortunately is invalid ('UPDATE permission missing on object .....). Isn't true : in case myValue is empty string or not null value - the requested column is updated without troubles

Comment: Can you update your question and post 1) full stack trace of hibernate exception and 2) SQL as generated by hibernate (you may need to set `hibernate.show_sql` property to true, if you haven't already). I've used bulk update to set values to NULL before and it worked with no problems - the issue is with your setup, not with Hibernate itself.

Comment: Note that setting null like this would *not* work `setParameter("param", myValue)`. Hibernate will not be able to figure out a proper type. Using setString would probably work. But also passing 3rd parameter works `setParameter("param", myValue, myType)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your update statement need to be done in HQL?  Do you have this table mapped to an entity in the system?  If you do, then you can simply set the property that maps to that column to null, and run a save on that entity. eg.

myObject.setMyProperty(null);
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(myObject);

That should work for you, but you gotta have an entity mapped to the table in question.

Comment: This can be significantly slower and invalidates the concept of batch-update queries.