# JPQL: set a column to null in an update

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, datanucleus

The following JPQL:

```
UPDATE SignIn signIn SET signIn.cookieUUID = null WHERE signIn.user.id = :userID
```

Gives me the following error because of the "= null":

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IS NULL WHERE `B0`.`ID` = 9' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

But it works when I set the field to an empty string (= '').

So how do you set a column to null using JQPL?

Comment: There is a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257736/how-to-put-null-into-column-using-hql) here (for HQL). It should help you to solve it. Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23708896)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think its `NULL` (in caps) ::Reference [JPQL](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html) and [Eclipselink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#WHERE_Clause)

```
 UPDATE SignIn signIn SET signIn.cookieUUID = NULL WHERE signIn.user.id = :userID
```

Or use param query as :

```
     String sQuery = "UPDATE SignIn signIn SET signIn.cookieUUID = :cookieUUID "+
                 "WHERE signIn.user.id = :userID";
     Query query= entityManager.createQuery(sQuery );
     query.setParameter("cookieUUID", null);
     query.setParameter("userID", userID);
     query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: This still gives me the very same error (and I also tried it before asking) ;)

Comment: The field is just annotated @Column, which implicitly means that the column is nullable.

Comment: @AndrewBourgeois: Is it possible for you to use param query? I tried with EclipseLink and seems to be working.

Comment: I know that it works that way, but I find it really awkward to do that when it really is static. Thanks for all the research, though!