# JPA. batch update with null

Tags: java, sql, jpa, null, sql-update

I want to do a batch update by simple query with two integer parameters:

```
    getEm().createQuery(
            " update" +
                    "   table " +
                    " set" +
                    "   DEADLINE = :deadline," +
                    "   PROLONGATION = :prolongation" +
                    " where" +
                    "   ID = :id")
            .setParameter("id", entity.getId())
            .setParameter("deadline", entity.getDeadline())
            .setParameter("prolongation", entity.getProlongation())
```

All works fine with not null value.
When I pass null. I got exception:

```
2016-07-01 15:35:15,707 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-24) SQL Error: 932, SQLState: 42000
2016-07-01 15:35:15,710 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-24) ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY
```

I see in log that null value not an Integer:

```
2016-07-01 15:35:15,690 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (default task-24) binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2016-07-01 15:35:15,693 TRACE [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (default task-24) binding parameter [2] as [VARBINARY] - [null]
```

I read next:
[How to put 'null' into column using HQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257736/how-to-put-null-into-column-using-hql)

**Update:** 
Field in my entity:

```
private BigDecimal id;

private Integer deadline;

private Integer prolongation;
```

Comment: Please writee entity objectt.

Comment: What has `HQL` to do with `JPA`?

Comment: @ululu: JPA defines a standard query language named JPQL. Hibernate is an implementation of JPA, and provides HQL, which is a superset of JPQL. So, they have much to do with each other.

Comment: @kotygoroshko why do you use an update query in the first place? Just get the entity and modify it. Hibernate will update the database for you.

Comment: @JBNizet I need to update a butch of entity.

Comment: all three parameters are representing numbers. are you passing only the numbers? In the database, are the columns mapped to correct data type?